# Exponential function giving different results in Java and Matlab

Tags: java, matlab

I have an n by 2 array 'ppi' having integer values(with duplicate), a second array n by 1 'gid' containing unique integer values from 'ppi' and a third array 'X0' with 0 and 1 values. Below is a MATLAB code which I want to implement in Java-

MATLAB version-

```
    gamma0 = 10; gamma1 = 10; beta = 20;
    delta = 0;weight=10;
    for i=1:length(gid)
    gconn = union(ppi(find(ppi(:,1)==gid(i)),2), ppi(find(ppi(:,2)==gid(i)),1));
    [a,b] = intersect(gid, gconn);
    u1 = (X0(i)*weight + sum(X0(b)==1))/(weight+length(gconn)); 
    u0 = ((1-X0(i))*weight + sum(X0(b)==0))/(weight+length(gconn));
    mrfpdf(i) = exp((1-X0(i))*(gamma0-beta*u1)+X0(i)*(gamma1-beta*u0))/(exp(gamma0-           beta*u1)+exp(gamma1-beta*u0));
    end
```

Java code for the same implementation

```
    double[] mrfpdf = new double[X0.length];
    Integer[] X = new Integer[X0.length];

    // find out unique class labels in ppi
    Set<Double> gid_set = new LinkedHashSet<Double>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ppi.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ppi[0].length; j++) {
    gid_set.add(ppi[i][j]);
    }
    }
    System.out.println("unique gid_set: " + gid_set);
    Double[] gid = gid_set.toArray(new Double[gid_set.size()]);
    Arrays.sort(gid);

    int gamma0 = 10, gamma1 = 10, beta = 20, delta = 0;weight=10;
    for (int i = 0; i < gid.length; i++) {

    Set<Double> ppi1 = new HashSet<Double>();
    Set<Double> ppi2 = new HashSet<Double>();
    for (int k = 0; k < ppi.length; k++) {
    if (ppi[k][0] == gid[i])
    ppi1.add(ppi[k][1]);

    if (ppi[k][1] == gid[i])
    ppi2.add(ppi[k][0]);

    }

    Set<Double> gconn = new HashSet<Double>(ppi1);
    gconn.addAll(ppi2);
    Set<Double> a = new HashSet<Double>(gid_set);
    a.retainAll(gconn);
    java.util.List<Double> buff = new LinkedList<Double>(gid_set);
    int[] b = new int[a.size()];// get index of intersection elements in this array
    int x = 0;
    for (double j : a) {
    for (int c = 0; c < gid.length; c++) {
    if (j == gid[c]) {
    b[x] = c;
    x++;
    }
    }
    }
    java.util.List<Double> X0_list = new ArrayList<Double>();
    for (double z : X0) {
    X0_list.add(z);
    }
    int sum1 = 0;
    for (int y : b) {
    if (X0_list.get(y) == 1)
    sum1++;
    }
    int sum2 = 0;
    for (int y : b) {
    if (X0_list.get(y) == 0)
    sum2++;
    }
    u1 = (int) ((X0[i] * weight + sum1) / (weight + gconn.size()));
    u0 = (int) (((1 - X0[i]) * weight + sum2) / (weight + gconn.size()));
    mrfpdf[i] = (Math.exp((1 - X0[i]) * (gamma0 - beta * u1) + X0[i]* (gamma1 - beta * u0)) / (Math.exp(gamma0 - beta * u1) + Math.exp(gamma1 - beta * u0)));

    }// end for(int i : gid)
    }
```

Can someone please tell me why the values in mrfpdf array is different in Java and Matlab code? Java code results in 0.99 and 0.5 values only whereas Matlab does not have any 0.5 value

Thanks

Comment: Would you mind formatting that? Nobody will read that!

Comment: And I am sure you are aware of [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matlab-code uses doubles while java-code uses integers (e.g. u0 and u1)

Comment: Thanks! I changed u1 and u2 to double and it worked!